# Framework headers suddenly not found

Tags: xcode

After upgrading to Mavericks and XCode 5.0.2, my project out of nowhere started giving me File Not Found errors on headers included from my custom frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to remove and readd each custom framework from the project. I hope this helps if anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw the same problem, framework headers suddenly becoming invisible to XCode. In my case, using XCode6 on Yosemite, it was because the symlinks (aka Aliases) (typically Headers, Resources, and the named library) in the framework had mysteriously lost their symlink metadata, and were seen by the finder as normal files. Because of this, the symlinks were not followed by XCode into the framework's Versions subfolders, and the files really were "not found".

Replacing the several frameworks which had this mysterious change (Parse & Crashlytics in my case) with fresh copies whose symlinks still showed their curved arrow in the finder cured XCode's confusion.

What makes this sort of failure particularly egregious is that the metadata is basically invisible to Git, so there's NO indication that your frameworks have been corrupted.
Yosemite subtly changed the behavior of symlinks, apparently changing their internal structure and deprecating some old Carbon APIs to them. This caused problems in apps and finder utilities that depended on the old Carbon APIs, including a favorite of mine "FinderPop" (since updated to correct the problem), so it's not entirely a surprise that Yosemite might occasionally manage to corrupt existing symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the problem was because of "spaces" in the parent folders of the items that I added.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/25009037/1071320

Just leaving this here in case some one else faces the same problem.