# Xcode: Framework Header File not found - Every time after new launch

Tags: ios, xcode, build, frameworks

Every time i open the project im working on, all header files of the frameworks are not linked. I have to manually add all frameworks reference so that xcode wouldn't give me the error that the header files is not found.

After quitting xcode and launching the project again, same thing.

If anyone could help it would be great ! its a huge pain in the ass tp link binary with libraries of all frameworks every time I launch the project.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same problem.When i quit Xcode and run again,every time i have to link my .a file..Any one have solution to this?

Comment: If you're working in Yosemite, this may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27165262/1028733

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its because of "spaces" in the names of the parent folders of the items that you added.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/25009037/1071320

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way which works for me

1. Create a group in Xcode
2. Drag the files inside the SDK to this folder

Build and Go!

N.B what i have tried earlier is drag the whole folder inside the SDK

Answer (score 0):

As @Shumais Ul Haq mentioned. It looks like it is happening because of spaces in the containing folder. When the framework is dragged into the project that spaces are messing in `Framework Search Paths`. The way to fix it without changing a directory names is to escape a spaces in the framework search path by `\` so instead of `../My Directory Name` it will be `../My\ Directory\ Name`